# How to rename an Android app so I can install it alongside a previous version

Tags: android-studio, apk, rename

I'm developing a new version of an app and I want to install it on my phone for testing, but I don't want it to replace the existing version which is already installed. I'm sure I can temporarily rename the new version somehow but I don't know exactly what I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

just change the applicationId in your build.gradle file
and return it back to default when you are done